# Custom post type permalink returns bad url

Tags: custom-post-types, php, html

I have problem with custom post type. In BO url's are ok example: `page.pl/post_type_name/post_title`.
When I try use `get_the_permalink()` or `the_permalink()` it return url like:
`/?post_type=cpt_wydarzenia&p=258`

Code:

```
    $args = array(
            "label" => __( "Wydarzenia", "vilo" ),
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
            //'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => false,
            'query_var' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'wydarzenia',
                'with_front' => true
            ),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'menu_i

          con' => 'dashicons-book',
                 'supports' => array(
                 'title',
                  'thumbnail',
            'comments',
            'editor'),
    );

    register_post_type( 'cpt_wydarzenia', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: Is the post 258 published? If no, then it's normal to have the "ugly" URL.

Comment: No it isn't. The post is planned. Is it possible, to planned post have normally url. I create incoming event based on custom post with planned public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) (which is used by `get_the_permalink()` and `the_permalink()`) returns the "ugly" URL if the post is not published, e.g. draft or scheduled, but you can use the following function instead which temporarily sets the post status to `publish` so that we'd get the pretty URL.

```php
function get_future_permalink( $id ) {
    if ( $post = get_post( $id ) ) {
        $post->post_status = 'publish';
        return get_permalink( $post );
    }
    return '';
}
```

So instead of `get_permalink( 258 )`, you'd use `get_future_permalink( 258 )`, where `258` is the post ID.

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly

Comment: My posts are published, but I am getting the "ugly" URL. If I enter the result of `get_permalink()` in the address bar, it redirects to the pretty permalink. I still have not figured out how to get the pretty permalink directly in code.

Comment: @GregPerham you can try flushing the rewrite rules by going to the permalink settings admin page (no need to click the "Save" button), and ensure one of the "pretty" permalink structures is being selected. If that doesn't work, try deactivating plugins and see if the issue persists - and if yes, then maybe the issue is with (a custom code in) the active theme on the site. But whether it's caused by a plugin or the active theme, you should post a new question and explain the issue in detail.